# how to set visibility of button from second activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-context

hello i have small problem with my android app
I have two classes: MainActivity and ViewDialogStop.

```
public class ViewDialogStop extends MainActivity{
public void showDialogStop(Activity activity){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_stop);


    ImageButton dialogButtonDone = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
    ImageButton dialogButtonExit = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
    dialogButtonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    dialogButtonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context ctx = v.getContext();
            stopNow(v);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

and in main activity

```
public void stopNow(View view){
Context ctx = view.getContext();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx,
                "This works!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();

        stopBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
```

but every time i received this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Toast message works but I need to set up stopBtn INVISIBLE how can I do that?

Comment: Your class `ViewDialogStop extends MainActivity`. This means that `ViewDialogStop` is an `Activity`. But it looks like you aren't using it as an `Activity`. Why is `ViewDialogStop` a separate class?

Comment: because it has a custom layout

Comment: How do you show your 2nd activity? Is it a problem if you just make it a regular dialog with a custom view?

Comment: thanks, regular dialog with a custom view - it is solution for me....so simple...nice! :)

Comment: @mask That means you have solved your problem or you need help?

Comment: it solved my problem, really simple solution :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not work. You cannot access the `View`s in one `Activity` from another `Activity`. A better approach would be to have `MainActivity` launch `ViewDialogStop` using `startActivityForResult()`. Then `ViewDialogStop` can set a "result" with data that gets passed back to `MainActivity` when it finishes. In `MainActivity` you override `onActivityResult()` (which will be called when `ViewDialogStop` finishes) and you can examine the returned "data" and based on that, you can call `stopNow()`.

Comment: @PrinceAli You should probably target your comment to OP and not to my answer.